# Unable to copy file from pod to my local desktop

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I know n number of time this question might haven been asked but still getting into an issue.. Can someone please help?

I am trying to copy a file called status.jar under app folder from a GKE pod to local using CloudSDK tool but failing will below error message.

PodName - central-v000-kjhs4

Namespace - oss-ns

ContainerName - service

Below is the error when i run the command, Error indicates that pod couldn't be found but pod name nor namespace nor container name are correct but still getting an error

kubectl cp default/central-v000-kjhs4:/app/status.jar -c service -n oss-ns ./Desktop/

**Error from server (NotFound): pods "central-v000-kjhs4" not found**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a syntax issue.

The official format for K8S copy is `kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar`

Try testing with the following:

```
kubectl cp oss-ns/central-v000-kjhs4:/app/status.jar -c service \Users\surendar\Downloads\test\status.jar
```

Suggestions:

1. Keep your destination path free of blank spaces to avoid CLI issues
2. Follow the backward/forward/trailing/leading slash syntax rule for your respective environment.
3. Refer to official `kubectl cp` documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp).

Comment: Thanks for response, used suggested command and getting the message as """tar: removing leading '/' from member names" and after that i don't see files downloaded in respective folders.   I searched in my Desktop folder where my OneDrive is placed and an another desktop folder which belongs to PC, neither areas i didnt found the jar copied.

Comment: @Surendar Try mentioning the absolute path to the directory you want to copy the files to.

Comment: kubectl cp oss-ns/central-v000-kjhs4:/app/status.jar -c service "C:\Users\surendar\OneDrive - Inc\Desktop"   --------> I am tying the command with the full path of my desktop and then i am giving error as "error: src doesn't exist in local filesystem"

Comment: @Surendar Try having no blank spaces in the path string, no spaces in **OneDrive - Inc**. Also, add a slash at the end of **'Desktop'**.

Comment: Same Error Abhinav - kubectl cp oss-ns/central-v000-kjhs4:/app/status.jar -c service "C:\Users\surendar\OneDrive-Inc\Desktop\" .... "error: src doesn't exist in local filesystem"error: src doesn't exist in local filesystem

Comment: @Surendar have a look at **mohansoundar**'s answer here, [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77310)

Comment: @Surendar Please could you confirm if above solution worked for you?

Comment: Finally it worked - Thank you ... i made the path to be very simple with no spaces & i wanted to copy it to path called - C:\Users\surendar\Downloads\test. Executed the command as  "kubectl cp oss-ns/central-v000-kjhs4:/app/status.jar -c service \Users\surendar\Downloads\test\status.jar  .... then it worked

Comment: @Surendar glad to know I could help! Spaces get very tricky in shells/CLI.

Comment: Please could you post the answer with the detailed solution? It will help the community a lot and it will increase your reputation as well :)

Comment: @Pedro I've improved my answer, you can refer to that.